Sorting a map by value properties: can these tests be shortened?
I'm trying to sort the map based on its value properties, such that:

all refCount of 0 appear first in loadstamp order; and then
the other non-zero refCount entries appear in loadstamp order regardless of the refCount.

The two versions shown provide the desired result (at least for this example map). Is it possible to make the if conditions in the sort function simpler, especially the refcount tests of either both rows being zero or both non-zero?


let m = new Map( [
['01001', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 19}})],
['01002', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 1}, loadstamp: { value: 18}})],
['01003', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 17}})],
['01004', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 3}, loadstamp: { value: 16}})],
['01005', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 15}})],
['01006', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 5}, loadstamp: { value: 14}})],
['01007', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 13}})],
['01008', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 2}, loadstamp: { value: 12}})],
['01009', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 11}})],
['01010', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 4}, loadstamp: { value: 5}})]
]
);

let iters = 0;
sorted = new Map( [...m].sort( (a,b) => {
  iters += 1;
  if (
      (   b[1].refCount === 0
       && a[1].refCount > 0
      )
    ||
      (   b[1].refCount > 0
       && a[1].refCount === 0
      )
  ) {
    return a[1].refCount - b[1].refCount;
  } else {
    return a[1].loadstamp - b[1].loadstamp;
  }
}));
console.log(`total iters: ${iters}`);
sorted.forEach( (v,k) =>
  console.log(`key: ${k}; refCount: ${v.refCount}; loadStamp: ${v.loadstamp}`)
);

iters = 0;
sorted = new Map( [...m].sort( (a,b) => {
  iters += 1;
  if (
      (   b[1].refCount === 0
       && a[1].refCount === 0
      )
    ||
      (   b[1].refCount > 0
       && a[1].refCount > 0
      )
  ) {
    return a[1].loadstamp - b[1].loadstamp;
  } else {
    return a[1].refCount - b[1].refCount;
  }
}));
console.log(`total iters: ${iters}`);
sorted.forEach( (v,k) =>
  console.log(`key: ${k}; refCount: ${v.refCount}; loadStamp: ${v.loadstamp}`)
);



total iters: 35
key: 01009; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 11
key: 01007; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 13
key: 01005; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 15
key: 01003; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 17
key: 01001; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 19
key: 01010; refCount: 4; loadStamp: 5
key: 01008; refCount: 2; loadStamp: 12
key: 01006; refCount: 5; loadStamp: 14
key: 01004; refCount: 3; loadStamp: 16
key: 01002; refCount: 1; loadStamp: 18
total iters: 35
key: 01009; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 11
key: 01007; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 13
key: 01005; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 15
key: 01003; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 17
key: 01001; refCount: 0; loadStamp: 19
key: 01010; refCount: 4; loadStamp: 5
key: 01008; refCount: 2; loadStamp: 12
key: 01006; refCount: 5; loadStamp: 14
key: 01004; refCount: 3; loadStamp: 16
key: 01002; refCount: 1; loadStamp: 18


It would almost certainly be more efficient to utilise the structure of the original data you're showing (e.g. alternating zero and non-zero refCount, descending loadstamp) than to sort it without making any assumptions. Even if you can't trust that, it may be more efficient in practice to rely on stable sorting - sort once by loadstamp, then again by refcount.

You can subtract boolean values of refCount > 0, when equal subtract loadstamp:


let m = new Map( [
['01001', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 19}})],
['01002', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 1}, loadstamp: { value: 18}})],
['01003', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 17}})],
['01004', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 3}, loadstamp: { value: 16}})],
['01005', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 15}})],
['01006', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 5}, loadstamp: { value: 14}})],
['01007', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 13}})],
['01008', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 2}, loadstamp: { value: 12}})],
['01009', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 0}, loadstamp: { value: 11}})],
['01010', Object.create(null, {refCount: {value: 4}, loadstamp: { value: 5}})]
]
);

let iters = 0;
sorted = new Map( [...m].sort((a,b) => {
  iters += 1;
  return (a[1].refCount > 0) - (b[1].refCount > 0) || a[1].loadstamp - b[1].loadstamp;
}));
console.log(`total iters: ${iters}`);
sorted.forEach( (v,k) =>
  console.log(`key: ${k}; refCount: ${v.refCount}; loadStamp: ${v.loadstamp}`)
);




Thank you. I expected I was doing it the hard way.
